# What should I look into to analyze emails comming in as a DataScientist?

Tags: nlp

I'm currently working as a DataScientist in a big company which means that we have a lot of emails comming in everyday and we would like to be able to classify them as accurately as possible.

Quantity of data is not a problem at all there. I can extract as many entrying mails as I want.

I just don"t really know where to start and have never been working in nlp problematics so I was wondering what ideas or techniqs you guys would come up with.

I'm interested either in ideas to analyze the data I have and also in models that I could come up with.
I don't want to go too much in details of where I work for some privacy reason but I might be able to answer some of your questions!

My main question is what to do with all this unclassified data. These mails are not tagged so how can I manage to create an nlp model and be able to evaluate his performances without being able to calculate a recall, a precision...

Would you also have any recommendation on which models to look into to analyse entrying mails. I'd like to tag them such as, billing, bug, question etc...

Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the research question? Is there any problem, anything to solve? Or just "here is a bunch of data,what can you tell us about it"?

Comment: I've never been working in nlp problematics, so I'm wondering where to start. There is not much code to post... Right now I have around 1,2 M entering emails and I don't know where to start. How to analyze it, what to do...

Comment: But what are you trying to find out from your data? What did your boss tell you they are interested in?

Comment: We would like to be able to find out what an email is related to and being able to be able to classify them. For example, billing, change of adress, bug using our tool...

Comment: And more precisely, we have data that we would like to create a model on. But these mails are at the moment never assigned a tag, so how could we create a model when we can't calculate accuracy, precision and recall?

Comment: this should all be part of your question. Right now your question is very broad to answer. I recommend you to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

may be converting them into tfidf matrix with frequent features and classify them is a starting point.